# MySQL query join, where for each result condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table: objects and tags. I've created a crosstable (sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the terminology...) called objects_tags which has a row for each tag associated with an object. Objects may have many tags, and tags may be associated with many objects.

So, objects might look like this

```
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
  | Object | Data                                   |
  |--------|----------------------------------------|
  |Object1 | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |Object2 | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |Object3 | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
```

Data doesn't matter. Tags looks basically the same, like:

```
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
  | Tag    | Data                                   |
  |--------|----------------------------------------|
  |Tag1    | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |Tag2    | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |Tag3    | Lorem Ipsum                            |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
```

My 'crosstable' looks like

```
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
  | Object | Tag                                    |
  |--------|----------------------------------------|
  |Object1 | Tag1                                   |
  |Object2 | Tag1                                   |
  |Object2 | Tag2                                   |
  |Object1 | Tag3                                   |
  |Object3 | Tag2                                   |
  |Object3 | Tag3                                   |
  |        |                                        |
  |        |                                        |
  +--------+----------------------------------------+
```

And what I would like to able to do is to get all the objects that have both Tag1 AND Tag2 (for example). Here, I would get back only object2.

The MySQL command that DOESN'T work is this:

```
SELECT * FROM objects JOIN objects_tags ON objects_tags.id=objects.id WHERE ( objects_tags.tag = ? AND objects_tags.tag = ? )
```

The ?'s are replaced with the tags I want to search against, wrapped as a PDO. This query returns nothing because no single row returned from the join has more than one tag associated with it, and I'm requesting rows which match multiple tags (here I use AND, using OR doesn't work either because it returns any row which matches any of the search terms. This result is too broad, I want ALL search terms matched). It should return multiple rows, with a single tag per row, each of which I'd like to search against. I'd like to return only objects which are tagged by some number of tags specified by the user, but I don't know how to form said query. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `objects_tags` requirements, so you need two `objects_tags` joins.

```
SELECT objects.Object
FROM objects
JOIN objects_tags ot1 ON (objects.Object = ot1.Object AND ot1.Tag = 'Tag1')
JOIN objects_tags ot2 ON (objects.Object = ot2.Object AND ot2.Tag = 'Tag2')
```

Comment: Okay, yes here I have two, but generally I need a variable number. Is there a mechanism you're aware of other than to dynamically generate these join statements?